# How to properly redirect from splash Screen to tabBarController?

Tags: ios

In a tabbar based application, I have created a splash screen and set it as a root view controller. In the splashViewController, I want to set the tabbar controller as the windows rootViewControoler.

```
 SplashViewController *splashViewController = [[SplashViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
splashViewController.loginview = loginview;

self.window.rootViewController = splashViewController;
```

//SplashViewController

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(animationFinished) userInfo:nil repeats:nil];

-(void)animationFinished
{
    Appdelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate);
    delegate.window.rootViewController = delegate.tabBarController;
}
```

All the code runs without any error, animation finished method is also called. However, the splash screen always stays and user is not redirected to tabBarController even after I set the windows rootViewController as tabbar Controller. What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you initialized tabBarController? Check if delegate.tabBarController is not nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler to start out with the tab bar controller as the root of your application and, if you absolutely must have a splash screen, present it as a modal display.  That way, when you dismiss the modal controller, you just continue with the real application.

Comment: if it's just a splash screen why not use the static image you have to supply with an app anyway?

Comment: @Nick - Possibly because it's one of the things that the interface guidelines explicitly says to avoid: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5

Comment: agreed, I wouldn't do it, but if you have a controller as your splash screen, you're going to have to submit a splash screen for your splash screen ;)

Comment: If I present the splash as a model display in viewDidLoad, then the problem is that it takes significant time for the view to load and the phone screen appears blank for few seconds.

Comment: you need to change your default.png @2x.png from a black image, to an image of your splash screen / interface.